# Python exit code

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, exit-code

quick question here.

When I run my Python script (Py 3.7.2) I got this code:
`Process finished with exit code -1`
In general I would expect `exit code 0`, but why there is `-1`?

Kind regards

UPDATE! 
I've added some code to give you an insight into my problem.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from lmfit import Model

def read_datafile(file_name):
    data = np.loadtxt(file_name, delimiter=' ')
    return data

def decomposition2(x, amp, cen, sig, e):
    return float(amp) * (1 + float(e) * (x - float(cen))) / (pow((x - float(cen)), 2) + pow((float(sig) / 2), 2))


for r in range(20, 91, 1):
    dataread = np.loadtxt("S:/Data/Model4/Mod{}.csv".format(r), delimiter=' ',
                          unpack=True)

    x = dataread[0,]
    y = dataread[1,]

    peak1b = Model(decomposition2, prefix='p1b_')
    peak2b = Model(decomposition2, prefix='p2b_')
    peak3b = Model(decomposition2, prefix='p3b_')
    peak4b = Model(decomposition2, prefix='p4b_')


    model2 = peak1b + peak2b + peak3b + peak4b

    params2 = model2.make_params(p1b_amp=1, p1b_cen=7.708, p1b_sig=4.43, p1b_e=0,
                                p2b_amp=1, p2b_cen=13.880, p2b_sig=5.26, p2b_e=0,
                                p3b_amp=1, p3b_cen=20.037, p3b_sig=5.78, p3b_e=0,
                                p4b_amp=1, p4b_cen=26.237, p4b_sig=6.16, p4b_e=0)

    result2 = model2.fit(y, params2, x=x, fit_kws={'maxfev':20000000})
    final2 = result2.best_fit
```

Comment: How much memory are you script using?

Answer (score 5):

Your process is being killed by signal 1 (HUP).

```
$ python3 -c 'import subprocess; print(subprocess.run(["cat"]).returncode)' & sleep 1 && pkill -HUP cat && fg
[1] 27339

[1]+  Stopped                 python3 -c 'import subprocess; print(subprocess.run(["cat"]).returncode)'
python3 -c 'import subprocess; print(subprocess.run(["cat"]).returncode)'
-1
```

In Python, processes killed by signals are given a negative exit status:
"A negative value -N indicates that the child was terminated by signal N (POSIX only)."
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html

HUP has integer value 1, so -N is -1.